# How To Fix : "Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: prefix is not defined"

Tags: javascript, discord

[image]

The error what i received is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: 
prefix is not defined
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\M\Desktop\LiveChatTwitch\BOT Discord\Index.js:31:80)
    at emit (events:513:28)
    at handle (c:\Users\M\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:28:14)
    at module.exports (c:\Users\M\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at handlePacket (c:\Users\M\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:354:31)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\M\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:238:12)
    at emit (c:\Users\M\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\M\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1103:51)
    at emit (c:\Users\M\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at onMessage (c:\Users\M\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:938:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Index.js:31
Process exited with code 1
```

I know the error was made by the facts, prefix is not defined but how i defined the prefix?

I try to found an solution, but nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the identifier *prefix* hasn’t been declared... and it’s most likely because you meant it as a string so put it in quotes like this:

```
message.content[0]=='prefix'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. It was indeed what you just pointed out to me.